# Keep parallax moving for one second on mouseout and stop smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouse, parallax

I would like to make a website with mouse parallax effect like in this page http://brightmedia.pl background mouse parallax is so smooth..

I have two questions:

1. When you mouseover on a container from, let's say, the top left corner, the image jumps. How can I make a smooth animation?
2. When you mouseout of a container, how can I make the image move a little bit and stop with a smooth animation?

What would code to solve these problems be?

Here is basic code:

```js
$('.container').mousemove( function(e){
    var xPos = e.pageX;
    var yPos = e.pageY;

  $('#par1').css({marginLeft: -xPos/20});

});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: grey;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container img {
  width: 110%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
}

body{
  height: 1000px;
}
h1{
  font-size: 60px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 30%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="container" id="container">
  <img id="par1" src="https://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" alt="">
  <h1>TEXT</h1>

</div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add transition to CSS

Comment: Did you even tried? If ill put transition and every time I will move the mouse, transition will be triggered and image will barely move at all.

Comment: `Did you even tried?` --> what if i ask you the same :) ... and i never meant to *simply* add transition and it will work by magic ... i meant that you can consider transition and elaborate more you code to obtain what you want

Comment: I am sorry, I mentioned I am entry level, but I really want to learn! If you would give me code example would be more clear what you want to advice me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I had solved the problem long time ago and I forgot about this post so I decided to update with the answer. Maybe it will be helpful for anyone else.

Problem solved by using GSAP. Below You can see the code that works exactly as I wanted

```js
    let wrap = document.getElementById('container');
   let request = null;
   let mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };
   let cx = window.innerWidth / 2;
   let cy = window.innerHeight / 2;
    
   document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    mouse.x = event.pageX;
    mouse.y = event.pageY;
      cancelAnimationFrame(request);
      request = requestAnimationFrame(update);
   });
    
   function update() {
    dx = mouse.x - cx;
    dy = mouse.y - cy;
    let tiltx = (dy / cy );
    let tilty = - (dx / cx);

      TweenMax.to("#container img", 1, {x:-tilty*20, y:-tiltx*20, rotation:0.01, ease:Power2.easeOut});
    }
    
    window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
       window.innerWidth / 2;
      window.innerHeight / 2;
    });
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
.container img {
  width: 110%;
  height: 120vh;
  position: absolute;
}
h1 {
  z-index:100;
  font-size: 6rem;
  z-index: 10;
  color:#333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="container">
  <img id="par1" src="https://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" alt="">
  <h1>GSAP Mouse Parallax</h1>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Temani said, playing with transition and eventually delay should do the job.

For 1st question: transition seems appropriate, associated with a mousein listener. Or even better, use the $(element).animate() function that allows to set the animation duration. That way, you don't set any value for transition duration.

For 2nd question: listener on mouseout > same process, but shorter animation (for the img shifting as well as the animation duration).

This should also give you some ideas:
https://codepen.io/Aldlevine/pen/Jowke

Based on Teemani below code example:

```js
$('.container').mousemove(function(e) {
  var xPos = e.pageX;
  var yPos = e.pageY;

  $('#par1').css("margin-left", -xPos / 10);

});
$('.container').mouseenter(function(e) {
  var xPos = e.pageX;
  var yPos = e.pageY;
  $('#par1').css("margin-left", -xPos / 10);
});
$('.container').mouseleave(function(e) {
  $('#par1').css({"transition": "margin-left 1s ease-in-out", "margin-left": "0"});
  setTimeout( function() {
    $('#par1').css("transition", "initial");
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: grey;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container img {
  width: 110%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  transition: margin-left 0.2s;
/*  transition: margin-left 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;*/
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 30%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="container">
  <img id="par1" src="https://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" alt="">
  <h1>TEXT</h1>

</div>
```

Comment: Any code example how to 'play' with transition? Because I tried with transition and jquery animation, but its every time i move mouse stucks and lagging.

Comment: Thank you as well for trying to help, but this is not good too. Im looking for smooth mouse parallax like in this page smooth background parallax http://brightmedia.pl

Answer (score 0):

You can rely one `mouseenter` / `mouseleave` to add animation:

```js
$('.container').mousemove(function(e) {
  var xPos = e.pageX;
  var yPos = e.pageY;

  $('#par1').css({
    marginLeft: -xPos / 10
  });

});
$('.container').mouseenter(function(e) {
  var xPos = e.pageX;
  var yPos = e.pageY;
  $('#par1').animate({
    "marginLeft": -xPos / 10
  }, "slow");
});
$('.container').mouseleave(function(e) {
  $('#par1').animate({
    "marginLeft": "0"
  }, "slow");
});
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: grey;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container img {
  width: 110%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 60px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 30%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
  <img id="par1" src="https://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" alt="">
  <h1>TEXT</h1>

</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but this is not good. I am trying to achieve mouse parallax effect like in this page background parallax is super smooth http://brightmedia.pl

Comment: @MantvydasBinderis in this case my advise is to use plugin  ... such paralax effect is not easy to achieve and also no need to re-invent the wheel, there is well known plugin .. here is an example http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/

Comment: Temani, but without plugin is very hard to make such mouse parallax? Because I want to learn by myself how to code it without any plugin help..

Comment: @MantvydasBinderis well it's not hard :) but it's not also easy ... am gonna edit my answer to show a better example

Comment: Ech.. I thought if is so easy to make image move on x axis (dont need y axis on this example) depending on mouse, so I thought as well will be easy to fix these jumps when I mouseover container from right or left top corner and add smooth transition when you move mouse out of container.. Thought professionals will show me 2 lines of code and will solve my problem but it seems its way more complicated.. but still dont want to use plugins...

Comment: @MantvydasBinderis it depend on the maner too, changin margin it's not the suitable one ... and the solution is not always 2 line of code :)

Comment: I know.. I want to learn so badly but cant find on web any solution for this, only plugins, plugins and plugins..

Comment: @MantvydasBinderis here is an easy example that you can follow : https://codepen.io/vajkri/pen/grgQmb

Comment: Yes, this is more closer to that one, just has annoying delay. But still nice example without plugin. Getting closer:)

Comment: @MantvydasBinderis you can start with it, understand it and then try to modify it ;)